# realization and generalization UML?

Tags: c#, uml

I don't understand the difference between 
the UML realization and generalization arrow in UML class diagrams. In my code specific, I created an interface:

```
public interface IParser {
   void Parse(string[] txtFile);
   void Add(List<char> gameMap);
}
```

And I inherit it:

```
public class ParseExits : IParser {

   public Dictionary<char, string> Dict { get;  }
   public List<Entity> EntityList  { get; }

   public ParseExits() {
            Dict = new Dictionary<char, string>();
            EntityList = new List<Entity>();
        }

   public void Parse(string[] txtFile) {
       ...
   }

   public void Add(List<char> gameMap) {
       ...
   }
```

I would say it's a realization as I inherit the whole interface. I realize the IParser (the "template"). Whereas a generalization would be to use some of the interface? Is this a correct distinction?

Comment: @momo : You are right. Please copy your comment to an answer. Please use comments to ask for clarification and not to give an answer.

Comment: Could you show a simple code-example of when generlization should be used instead of realization? And thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can say that `IParser` **is realized** (implemented) by `ParseExits`. Generalization is different and occurs when you use inheritance. For example the base class "Animal" and the class that inherits from an animal: "Tiger". In this case, you can call it "**is a**" relationship. A "Tiger" is an "Animal". A "Tiger" **is generalized** by "Animal.

Your second question is more of a “general object-oriented” question.

**Inheritance vs composition**: Generally speaking, it is more robust to use composition instead of inheritance and it is not so easy to get rid of your genes. (google composition over inheritance)

**Interface vs (abstract) class**: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/761342/4033690) StackOverflow answer